# Better Visual Studio Version for XML Web Services

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create an application will consume XML web service from one of our vendors. The application has to import data by XML web service from their server. This is my first XML Web service project, so I want to use best tool that I can use. I can simply assume latest Visual Studio 2010 is the best one to use, but I just don't want to assume it because I have never tried with any versions of visual studio for a XML Web service. This is what I want to do. If VS2010 and VS2008 provide same functionality for  XML Web services, then I'd like to use VS2008. What do you think? Please, advise me. Always thanks for any answers.

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting that Microsoft might have made Visual Studio 2010 _worse_ for accessing web services?

Comment: That's not what I meant. I just want to know what MS has done for VS 2010 for XML Web Services to make it better or easier if I have to use VS2010. By the way, I mainly use VS 2008 that is the reason I ask this.

Comment: Upgrade to VS2010. It's a major improvement in all ways. Get the Trial edition, then open an XML schema and look at the schema viewer, or open an XML file and attach its schema to it, and watch XML Intellisense work far better than before. That should sell you on it as far as XML is concerned. Use it for a week and you'll buy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Visual Studio 2010. Use "Add Service Reference" to add a reference to a web service into your project.

Comment: Do you know what has been improved in VS 2010 in terms of XML Web Services for developer? Like easier or technically better?

Answer (score 1):

Check out:

[A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx)

and see all the improvement that have been made to WCF (which is the default standard for web services since .NET 3)...

WCF supports both using SOAP, as well as REST, which is (vastly simplified) XML-over-HTTP / XML Web Services.